# Doubled-up LED lamp wiring found

Tags: led, wiring

[image]

Can someone explain what kind of LED lamp this is and why it takes two live wires and two neutral wires? I am based in the US. I can’t find this anywhere online. There's no real identifier seen on the lamp, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't tell you what kind of lamp it is, because that wiring is pretty standard. It has an incoming live and neutral, and an outgoing live and neutral, to connect other lamps in parallel with it more easily.

Comment: I see makes sense. What seems redundant is that where they all join at the top, the connection there is already making it parallel before the bulb is even reached. I guess in case you don’t have those plugs/joiners it makes sense!

Comment: Actually... to me it looks like there are two lamps inside that housing, and each of them has a separate pair of wires that go up to the wire nuts. Perhaps it's intended to mimic the three-way incandescents (50 / 100 / 150) and has simply been wired for maximum brightness.

Comment: @tsc_chazz that was my other concern... are there 2 separate lamps/circuits in that housing!!